# angular.js - naming the form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have categories page where are listed all products with its forms.
E.g.

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
   <form name="product[[ product.id ]]"></form> // [[]] custom angular syntax, result is product1,2,3
</div>
```

Then I have product page where is same form. When I try to apply same naming convention

```
<form name="product[[ product.id ]]"></form>
```

It just doesn't work. Result is just `product`. Why it doesn't accept that name? When I change it to something else e.g. `coolName[[ product.id ]]` it works(coolName1).

It's just acting weird. Also 1 directive(image jQuery slider, which should wait until dom is loaded) doesn't work for me on that page.

Any thoughts?

Comment: because `product` in `<form name>` gets the value from your `ng-repeat="product in products">`

Comment: Can you try this? : `<form name="[[ 'product' + product.id ]]"></form>`

Comment: @RazvanBalosin yes you are right, thanks. valverde93 yes I'm sure, Antonio that also doesn't work, problem was in product variable name

Comment: Is it possible `product.id` is not set for your `products` on the product page, and is set on the categories page?

Comment: nope, data are same so id is on both pages, first comment solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because in your

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">  <!-- product as repeater for products -->
   <form name="product[[ product.id ]]"></form> <!-- product get's value from repeater -->
</div>
```

You have to either change `ng-repeat="something in products"`

#### **or**

change the form name to `<form name="something[product.id]">`